# Convert latitude, longitude in to address as a string

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

Please help me resolve this problem.
I want to get address from latitude, longitude in Google Maps.
Here is my functions:

```
function codeLatLng() {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var lati = document.getElementById("latitude_value").value;
var lngi = document.getElementById("longitude_value").value;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, lngi);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var ngo;
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) {
      map.setZoom(11);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
      });
      ngo = results[1].formatted_address;
      infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
  }
});
return ngo;
 }
```

When this function is executed. The address is displayed in Maps.
**However, this is not what I need. I just want to assign this address to variable 'ngo' as a string.**
This function return 'ngo' which is displayed in the text field as 'undefinded'.
I need some help to solved this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: where and what code are you using to display `ngo` in the text field?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to assign this address to variable 'ngo' as a string.

That's the problem right there. You can't do that. JavaScript just doesn't work that way. The geocoder call is *asynchronous*. It returns before the data is received from the server. The data isn't ready until the geocoder callback function is called.

What you need to do instead is to use that `ngo` data in the callback function itself, or call another function and pass it the data, and use the data there.

For example, where you have this line:

```
ngo = results[1].formatted_address;
```

you can replace it with:

```
useNGO( results[1].formatted_address );
```

where `useNGO` is a function you've defined (anywhere) like this:

```
function useNGO( ngo ) {
    // Do stuff with ngo here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that using the `var` keyword when declaring `var ngo` makes `ngo` a local variable, so it doesn't exist outside of `codeLatLng()`. Try deleting `var ngo`, placing `ngo = "";` somewhere outside of any function declarations (like right before `function codeLatLng() {`), and let me know if that works :)

Comment: I try it! But It not work. The problem is I don't really know the way geocoder execute. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: can you put `console.log(results[1].formatted_address);` right before `ngo = results[1].formatted_address;` and see what the console says?